# Extract hours from time

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am try to find solution but I couldn't. The problem is following.

```
   1 ) I want to extract hours from time and add minutes converted to hours

 (SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0))
```

So for example If I have 16hours:35minutes. I want to display 16 and minutes part should be added to hours as 16,5 hours for example

```
2) extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)

LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
```

I found this part of solution but this soulution is wrote in MySQL and  I need Oracle SQL solution

```
CONCAT(
                    -- extract hours froAm time and add minutes converted to hours
                   (SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNCATE((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0))
                    , ':', 
                    -- extract minutes from time and find reminder (modulo)*/
                    LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
                ) AS W_TOTAL_SUM
```

Also I try to convert this MySQL statment to Oracle SQL by using following site, but unfortunettly I didn't get correct result since it returns same `output` as `input`

http://www.sqlines.com/online

So exactly same as I decribe but only in Oracle SQL. I would be very thankfull since I try to fix this problem a couple of hours and couldn't find any solution for this problem

Here is my solution which doesn't work. I get error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis



   SELECT  
           (SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', 1)) + TRUNC((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) / 60),0)), ':' ,
             MOD(LPAD(SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)), 60),2,0)
           -- MOD(LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0) 
            --  LPAD((SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)) % 60), 2, 0)
                    AS TOTAL_SUM FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        ata.ATAID AS AtaId, ata.ProjectID, ata.StartDate, ataAW.Quantity
                    FROM 
                        ata
                    INNER JOIN 
                        weekly_report
                    ON
                        weekly_report.ataId = ata.ATAID
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles  ataAW 
                    ON 
                        ataAW.wrId = weekly_report.id 
                    WHERE 
                        ata.ATAID = 10987
                    AND 
                        ataAW.type = 1
                    OR 
                        ataAW.type = 2
                    OR
                        ataAW.type = 3
                    AND
                        (weekly_report.status != 3 AND weekly_report.status != 4)
                    AND
                    (
                        weekly_report.year < (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                        OR
                        (
                            weekly_report.year <= (SELECT year FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                            AND
                            weekly_report.week <= (SELECT week FROM weekly_report WHERE id = 89)
                        )
                    )
                ) A 
                 group by A.AtaId
                 order by A.AtaId ASC
```

The common problem is

```
LPAD((SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60), 2, 0)
```

Here is output which I expect

```
TOTAL_SUM
101:24
```

Comment: Why on earth do you store time values as string? You should convert it to appropriate data type, e.g. `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` or `INTEGER` number of seconds.

Comment: Modulo in Oracle is `MOD()`, so try `MOD(SUM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(aa.Quantity, ':', -1)), 60)`

Comment: I have no idea why I store TIME value as string. I see that is common problem

Comment: I know that Modulo in Oracle is MOD() but doesn't work. I get error Missing right paranthesis

Comment: You did `(SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)) MOD 60)` - which is PL/SQL and different to `MOD(SUM(SUBSTR(A.Quantity, ':', -1)), 60)`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  I update my quetion right now. You can check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223348/discussion-between-don-julian-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understood the question:

- sample data in lines #1 - 2
- extract hours (line #3)
- extract minutes (line #5), divide it by 60 (as number of minutes in an hour)
- hours + minutes = result

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '16hours:35minutes' from dual)
  3  select to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1)) -- hours
  4         +
  5         round(to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2)) / 60, 2) -- minutes
  6         as result
  7  from test
  8  /

    RESULT
----------
     16,58

SQL>
```